# Is There a Way to do Binomial Regression in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark, statistics, apache-spark-mllib, glm

I'm working with a PySpark dataframe and I need to do a **Binomial** regression, with more than one trial in each row. For example, my table looks like this:

```
┌──────────┬──────────┬─────────────┬────────────┐
│ Features │ # Trials │ # Successes │ # Failures │
├──────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼────────────┤
│      ... │       10 │           4 │          6 │
│      ... │        7 │           2 │          5 │
│      ... │        5 │           4 │          1 │
└──────────┴──────────┴─────────────┴────────────┘
```

I don't want to 'ungroup' the data. In `statsmodels`, there is a possibility to directly do a Binomial Regression on the grouped data with a patsy formula:

`formula = '# Successes + # Failures ~ Features'`

Is there a way to do so in PySpark as well?